# Boost.IOStreams: How to correctly redirect file streams with 'rdbuf'?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, io-redirection, boost-iostreams

I cannot possibly find explanation for the following behavior:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

TEST_CASE(rdbuf) {
  {
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_sink> file("test");

    file << "Hello, World!";
  }
  {
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_source> file("test");
    std::string                                             line;

    std::getline(file, line);
    CHECK_EQUAL(line, "Hello, World!");
  }
  {
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_source> file("test");
    std::istringstream                                      iss;
    std::string                                             line;

    file.rdbuf(iss.rdbuf());

    std::getline(file, line);
    CHECK_EQUAL(line, "");

    std::getline(iss, line);
    CHECK_EQUAL(line, ""); // (1) Why?
  }
  {
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_source> file("test");
    std::ostringstream                                      oss;
    std::string                                             line;

    file.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());

    std::getline(file, line);
    CHECK_EQUAL(line, "");

    line = oss.str();
    CHECK_EQUAL(line, ""); // (2) Why?
  }
}
```

In both instances `(1)` and `(2)`, I rather expected

```
CHECK_EQUAL(line, "Hello, World!");
```

to succeed.

What do I actually miss here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the wrong way round. You're assigning the `streambuf` from the `istringstream` to the `filestream` and you ought to do it in the other direction. I.e.:

```
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_source> file("test");
std::istringstream                                      iss;
std::string                                             line;

iss.rdbuf(file.rdbuf()); //assign the file to iss

std::getline(file, line);
CHECK_EQUAL(line, "Hello, World!");

std::getline(iss, line);
CHECK_EQUAL(line, ""); // Empty, because the streambuf is shared.
```